# Print JSON Data in output within FLASK

Tags: python, json, flask

So I have this test app (learning flask). It takes a username and a message input and displays it on the third page. The last "return" below spits out that data. I need to include the JSON equivalent of the data below it. I think I need to put 'username' and 'message' into a variable and call json dumps to return it also? killing myself over here.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,
redirect,  url_for,abort, session
import json
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'F34TF$($e34D';

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
 def signup():
    session['username'] = request.form['username']
    session['message'] = request.form['message']
    return redirect(url_for('message'))

@app.route('/message')
 def message():
    if not 'username' in session:
        return abort(403)
    return render_template('message.html', 
            username=session['username'],message=session['message']),

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: one thing.. your indentation is messed up... your "def" lines should not be indented the way they are. Among other things...

Comment: is that all you have to add? really? thanks for the insightful input.

Comment: you're welcome... it just makes me wonder if you had actually tried to run it. Can you provide some detail on what error you're seeing vs what you expect. It would make it easier to help.

Comment: it runs fine. Just havent mastered pasting the code. no error, just want the json data returned with username and message output. As it says in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify) is what you need. The page also has example. You can do something like below. Normally you would want to respond with either a html or json depending on the accept header. It defines what data the client is expecting. 
If accept is 'application/json' use jsonify. if accept is 'text/html', then render your template. That way your page will be normal when loaded from browser, however when using a restclient with accept headers set appropriately, you get json responses.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/message')
def message():
   if not 'username' in session:
       return abort(403)
   if request.headers['accept'] == 'text/html':
       return render_template('message.html', 
           username=session['username'],message=session['message'])
   elif request.headers['accept'] == 'application/json':
       return jsonify(
           username=session['username'], message=session['message'])
```

Comment: if I wanted it displayed with the same output, where would I put this? Nest it in @app.route('/message')?

Comment: think I am on the wrong path...

Comment: @app.route('/message')
    def message():
    if not 'username' in session:
        return abort(403)

    return render_template('message.html', username=session['username'], message=session['message']),

    return render_template jsonify('message.html', username

Comment: just saw your example.. trying..

Comment: If you want it displayed, you have to make a dict of the variables you want, use json.dumps() and stick that string somewhere in your template.  (jsonify replaces render_template)